# HTML element not in source code showing up in DOM?

Tags: html, dom

I am new to web dev and am creating a simple HTML/CSS personal site, and have come across a frustrating bug. An extra element not in my source code shows up in the DOM three times.
The header in my source code looks like the following (the icons are displayed for larger screens, text links for smaller screens):

```
  <header>
    <div class="icons">
      <span><img src="assets/profile.svg"></span>
      <span><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/aboutme1.svg"></a></span>
      <span><a href="writings.html"><img src="assets/writings1.svg"></a></span>          
      <span><img src="assets/resume2.svg"></span>
      <span><a href="links.html"><img src="assets/links1.svg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="textlinks">
      <a href="index.html">about me</a>
      <a href="writings.html">writing samples</a>
      <a href="#"><i>résumé</i></a>
      <a href="links.html">links</a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

But the DOM inspector shows the following (arrows pointing to elements of mysterious origin):

```
  <header>
    <div class="icons">
      <span>...</span>
      <span>...</span>
      <span>...</span>
      <span>...</span>
      <span>...</span>
      <a href="links.html"></a>     <---
    </div>
    <a href="links.html"></a>       <---
    <div class="textlinks">
      <a href="links.html"></a>     <---
      <a href="index.html">about me</a>
      <a href="writings.html">writing samples</a>
      <a href="#"><i>résumé</i></a>
      <a href="links.html">links</a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

What could be the cause of those extra link elements? They only show up on one of the four subpages, even though the other three have the same source HTML/CSS. There is no Javascript. This messes up the format of the page for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line here:

```
<span><a href="links.html"><img src="assets/links1.svg"></span>
```

you have an unclosed `<a>`.